# How to perform an operation in post section of rpm spec only when reinstalling the rpm

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I have a use case where I want to execute a particular command in the post section of rpm spec only when same version of rpm is already installed. Rpm will be invoked with following option:

```
rpm -Uvh --replacefiles --replacepkgs rpm_file_name
```

Condition `if [ "$1" = "2" ];` is not useful here because it becomes true for upgrades also.

How can a reinstall case be detected in spec?

Comment: Isn't `$1` set to `1` for a reinstallation since at the end there will only be one version of the package installed? That doesn't help you directlysince it just inverts the problem meaning you can't tell an installation from a reinstallation but it changes what you need to distinguish.

Comment: Yes. That`s right. Then we need some way to distinguish install and reinstall.

Comment: Create a file at the end of `%post`? But what is your actual goal here? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is parsing a `version.txt` file somewhere in your files. Like you said, the counts wouldn't help for upgrade vs. reinstall, etc. As Etan asked, why? A nice hook is `%verify` and that might be better for what you need if you explain what it is...

Answer (score 0):

This is a very exotic demand. There is no straightforward solution for this, but there is a way around:

```
%post
if [ $1 -eq 2 ]
then
    # this means the package is being updated; not being installed for the first time
    if [ $(rpm -q %{name} | wc -l) == 1 ]
    then
        # normally the "old" and the "new" version are both installed at this point. If only one is installed, that means we are reinstalling the exact same package
    fi
fi
```

Comment: I will try this. One question: I think that we have limitations in running 'rpm' command from with in the spec file. The RPM will be putting some lock which may cause some issues. Will that be a problem here?

Comment: I expected this problem as well, but this is not the case. Rpm only puts a lock when really necessary. I have tested my proposition on an opensuse 13.1 where it worked just fine.